# How to group same topics under the first one using vba

Tags: excel, vba, grouping

I'm making a sheet that's supposed to automatically update using information on another tab.

The last step that I've still got to figure out how to do is automatically grouping cells with same value under the first time that value appears using vba.

Here's an image of what I'd like to achieve using vba:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.  You'll have to make an attempt first and show us your code so we can help debug issues rather than asking someone to write the code for you.

Comment: Try filtering the `Project` column and use that range to build your sheet. Also, have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Look into `Range.Group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try to this...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Group()

Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RowsInRange As Long
Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 4 To LastRow

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1)
RowsInRange = RowsInRange + 1
i = i + 1
Loop

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i - RowsInRange, 1).Font.Bold = True
Set rng = Range(Cells(i - RowsInRange + 1, 1), Cells(i, 1))
rng.Select
Selection.Rows.Group

RowsInRange = 0

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you soooo so much!! It's exactly what I needed